# Force vue.js to refresh prop when it's sub-property is changed

Tags: typescript, vue.js

I have a component that binds on an object, and the parent component changes a property of its object. The subcomponent should react to the change.

Subcomponent:

```
import { Component, Emit, Inject, Model, Prop, Provide, Vue, Watch } from 'vue-property-decorator'

@Component({
    props: {
        value: Object,
    }
})
class ValidatedSummaryComponent extends Vue {
    value: any;
    field = "Name";
    v: any;

    created() {
        console.log("!", this.value);
        this.v = this.value;
    }

    state: string | null = null;
    error = "";

    @Watch('value')
    onValueChanged(val: any, oldVal: any) {
        console.log("Value called", val);
        this.v = val;
        this.onChanged();
        this.$forceUpdate();
    }

    private onChanged() {
        if (typeof this.v.validationErrors[this.field] == 'undefined') {
            this.state = null;
            this.error = "";
        } else {
            this.state = 'invalid';
            this.error = this.v.validationErrors[this.field].join();
        }
    }
}

export default ValidatedSummaryComponent;
```

Usage:

```
<ValidatedSummary v-bind:value="bindableObject"></ValidatedSummary>
```

Then I do:

```
bindableObject.Name = 'New name'
```

and I need my component `ValidatedSummaryComponent` to react.

I probably could bind it as a separate property:

`<ValidatedSummary v-bind:value="bindableObject.Name"></ValidatedSummary>`

, but **in the end design, the component should watch for all of the properties of `BindableObject` and there will be a few different `BindableObjects` with different set of properties, so I can't just bind it property by property.**

The only way I managed to make it work is to force vue.js to update the whole object ensuring vue.js equality check does not pass:

```
this.bindableObject = Object.assign(new BindableObject(), this.bindableObject );
```

But this is very cumbersome as I will have to do this on every change so I'm looking for a better way to handle this. 
It would also be nice to remove `this.$forceUpdate();` in the code above, but I can survive with it.

Comment: https://vuejs.org/v2/guide/reactivity.html#Change-Detection-Caveats

Comment: @MartinBean I am aware of that. The object is fully observed and completely functional out of the sub-component

Comment: You can try using the `deep` option of `watch` as shown in the manual https://vuejs.org/v2/api/#watch

Comment: @IVOGELOV Wow! That is exactly what I was looking for. If you can put it as an answer - I'll accept it

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Converting my comment into an answer.

You can try using the `deep` option of `watch` as shown in the [manual](https://v2.vuejs.org/v2/api/#watch)

Answer (score 7):

Well just do a force update. It will make your life easier

```
vm.$forceUpdate();
```

As mentioned in docs

> Force the Vue instance to re-render. Note it does not affect all
>   child components, only the instance itself and child components with
>   inserted slot content.

However it's only recommended when you have no other options left(Only as a last option).

So what other options can you use make it work.(depends on code design)

1. Try using Vue.set(). or,
2. Reassign the changed object.

Comment: Unfortunately, this doesn't always cause the update and doesn't help me in my situation. I have a) a component with props b) deep dependency c) the entity that is set to props passes vuejs equality check, which also prevents it from refreshing. Not sure which one of these three or all, but this is what cause the problem for me

Comment: Awesome, thank you! Using an element didn't work, but it did on the entire `Vue` instance with `this.$forceUpdate`